# Swift - Cannot assign to `delegate` in `newView`

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am using Swift to implement a delegate for a custom class I created. However, when trying to set the delegate to self, I get an error that states "Cannot assign to 'delegate' in 'newView'. Am I missing something here?

In my View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyDelegate...

var newView = MyClass(frame: CGRectMake(pointX, pointY, 80, 80))
newView.delegate = self

func sayHi() {
    print("Hi");
}
```

In my custom class:

```
protocol MyDelegate {
    func sayHi()
}

class MyClass: UIView {
    let delegate : MyDelegate?

    func someMethod() {
        delegate?.sayHi()
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you make sure the class conforms to its own protocol? More code would be helpful, especially the part where you declare the protocol and delegate.

Comment: What is the type of delegate and self?

Comment: just updated with more code

Comment: Can you post the code where you create an instance of MyClass and assign the delegate and call the method?

Comment: That is included in the View Controller code, which I have added to the top of my question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you call someMethod somewhere?

Comment: yep, someMethod is called when a UIButton is tapped in the main view controller...just cant seem to get passed the error where I am assigning the delegate

Comment: maybe try `var delegate : MyDelegate?`

Comment: Wow that worked! Thanks so much! I'm going to have to do some research on when to use let versus when to use var. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you upvote my comment and select ad121's response as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `delegate` property declared with `let`. Thus, it can only be assigned to in a constructor. Change it to `var delegate` and it should work.